# Query to count number followers swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to count the number of followers the user has from my firebase database but no success. The number of followers is returning any value. When a user follows another user it creates a node in firebase with the userID and a Int value of 1 as shown below.

```
 fileprivate func countTrusting() {

    guard let userId = self.user?.uid else { return }

    guard let currentLoggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    Database.database().reference().child("following").child(userId).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: 1).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let count = String(snapshot.childrenCount)
        self.trustedLabel.text = "\(count) \nFollowing"

    }) { (error) in
        print("There was an error getting the following count:", error)
    }
}
```

My firebase database

[image]

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. If you place a breakpoint in the closure (e.g. on `let count = String(snapshot.childrenCount)`), does it get hit when you run the code in a debugger?

Comment: Yes, when I place a break point on let count = String(snapshot.childrenCount) It reaches it.

Comment: So what's the value of `count` at that point? I'm trying to help here, but Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so be creative in how you use the tools that are available to you to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to have a count of the number of followers of a user. In that case, there's no need for a query as the only nodes that will exist are the users followers.

This code reads in the child followers nodes and prints the count.

```
let userFollowingRef = fbRootRef.child("following").child("some_user_uid")
userFollowingRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount)
})
```